# Laplacian filter returning very black image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to apply a local Laplacian filter to an image using `blockproc` but the result I get is far darker than the result in the textbook. I've seen some other posts about this same problem but I'm not sure what exactly I'm failing to grasp.

My code:

```
img1 = im2double(imread('Fig0352(a)(blurry_moon).tif'));
kernel = [0 1 0; 1 -4 1; 0 1 0];

%generate laplacian image
fun = @(block_struct)laplacian_kernel(block_struct.data, kernel);
img2 = blockproc(img1, [3 3], fun, 'PadPartialBlocks', true, 'TrimBorder', true);
img3 = img2(:, 1:end-2);%crop extra two columns added by last passthrough of blockproc
img4 = imsubtract(img1,img3);%get enhanced image

%display
figure;
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(img1)
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(img3);
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(img4);


function f = laplacian_kernel(img, kernal)
%want to pad this 3x3 chunk of the image so we don't exceed the bounds of
%the array when doing laplacian
img1 = padarray(img, [1 1]);
out = zeros(size(img1));
for i = 2 : (length(img1)-1)
   for j = 2 : (length(img1)-1)
       neighborhood = img1(i-1: i+1, j-1: j+1);%get neighborhood
       out(i,j)= sum(neighborhood .* kernal, 'all'); 
   end
end
f = out(2:length(img1)-1, 2:length(img1)-1);%remove padding
end
```

And the image I'm getting is

[image]

The laplacian is the image on the top right, which is far darker than what is shown in the book.

The image from the book looks much more like this:

[image]

I know it's still very dark (and a small image, sorry) but there is much more detail to it than what I'm producing with my custom code. What am I doing wrong with my laplacian? I've tried rewriting the code multiple times but always get more or less the same result.

If I use `nlfilter`, my result matches that in the book. However, it takes so much more time I don't like to use it. I'm clearly stumbling when piecing the blocks back together with blockproc but I can't conceptualize where I'm going wrong. Here are my results when using nlfilter:

```
img1 = im2double(imread('Fig0352(a)(blurry_moon).tif'));

kernel = [0 1 0; 1 -4 1; 0 1 0];
k2 = [1 1 1; 1 -8 1; 1 1 1];

fun = @(x)laplacian_kernel(x, kernel);
img2 = nlfilter(img1, 'indexed', [3 3], fun);

img3 = imsubtract(img1, img2);

figure;
subplot(1,3,1);
imshow(img1);
title('original image');
subplot(1,3,2);
imshow(img2);
title('laplacian using nlfilter');
subplot(1,3,3);
imshow(img3);
title('enhanced image');

function f = laplacian_kernel(img, kernal)
f = sum(img.*kernal, 'all');
end
```

With output:

[image]

Clearly, the results from `nlfilter` are much better. I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong with blockproc.

Comment: I guess that you should normalized the output to fit between 0 and 1 (or 0 and 255, or whatever you need). Also I would use a 2D convolution to apply the kernel to your image, something like `conv2(img,kernel,'same')`.

Comment: @obchardon Thanks for the suggestion. However, normalizing the image will make it look nicer but it still doesn't solve my issue with the enhancement. The book image I'm comparing to (for the laplacian) is not normalized. For some reason when I use nlfilter, my answer matches the book but it just takes so much longer I don't like using it. I'm clearly missing something when piecing the blocks back together but I'm just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The typical output of a Laplace operator is very dark, and approximately half of its pixels have a negative value. To display it properly, instead of `imshow(img3)`, use `imshow(img3,[])`. This will scale the image so its minimum value is black and its maximum value is white. Most pixels will now be middle-gray with positive pixels closer to white and negative pixels closer to black.

But you have a bigger problem in the code: by processing each 3x3 block with zero padding, only one pixel in that block has the right value, the other 8 pixels sample some of that padding. You want to use the `BorderSize` option in `blockproc` instead of your zero padding:

```matlab
img2 = blockproc(img1, [3 3],  @(s)conv2(s.data, kernel, 'same'), ...
                 'PadPartialBlocks', false, ...
                 'BorderSize', [1,1], 'TrimBorder', true);
img3 = img1 - img2;
```

We’re using `conv2` now, because that’s all we need, there’s no need to re-invent the wheel. But if you do want to use your own code for filtering, consider swapping your two loops, because it’s more efficient that way, and use `size(img,1)` and `size(img,2)` instead of `length(img)`.

Note that not padding partial blocks should make your subsequent image trimming unnecessary.

Using bigger blocks than 3x3 will make this more efficient.

---

To emulate `conv2` with `blockproc`, use 1x1 blocks with a 1-pixel border (giving a 3x3 window into the image), and use the dot product with the kernel as your block processing function:

```matlab
img2 = blockproc(img1, [1 1],  @(s)sum(s.data(:).*kernel(:)), ...
                 'BorderSize', [1,1], 'TrimBorder', false);
img3 = img1 - img2;
```

This is obviously not at all fast, writing a convolution by hand as a double loop results in code about 5x as fast as using `blockproc`.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid conv2, but thank you for the response. I'll definitely look at BorderSize and see where that takes me.

Comment: @Ben You can emulate `conv2` with `blockproc` by processing in 1x1 blocks. The padding added will give your function a 3x3 region of the image, abd the dot product with your 3x3 kernel will give you the right result.

Comment: @Ben See the edit.